# Is it a good practice to unit test asynchronous code?

Tags: java, android, testing

It is definitely possible to test asynchronous code by letting the thread wait until the asynchronous code finishes. However, is it encouraged to test asynchronous code. Or instead, should we seperate the logic and only test the synchronous part?

For example, in my app I would make a REST API call to fetch json from server and then I need to parse the json.

There are two approaches:

1. Test the fetching and parsing as a whole. We can use `MockWebServer` to simulate timeout and response.

   -Cons: it would bring some complexity.
2. Just test the parsing part, since we cannot control the API call part; it is controlled by `okhttp`

   --Cons: Hard to cover timeout case.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to combine two tests, the first parsing and second simulating timeout. Both are different test cases. If you can write both using MockWebServer, then that'd be my way to go.

Comment: Test all code that isn't trivial.  Unit tests are typically isolated, with no dependencies on external systems, so they can be repeatedly executed with fast results.  Why would mocking an external dependency be complex?  Perhaps the code is not written to be unit testable?  Integration tests are also useful though, especially for debugging without having to have the full app up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your question specially ask about "Unit tests", the simple answer is "No". unless the unit you test is not interested of the result of Async call, it is not a part of your unit.unit tests should only make sure your unit works properly. in this case you should verify Async call is dispatched properly (so it will be a white box test).

Answer (score 0):

Test are organized in hierarchy. The lowest level tests logic, the next level tests how the logic is called within framework (in your case, asynchronous http), and finally, manual tests with browser (if you are making a website). All levels must be tested. Often all program units work well but the application does not.